# Declare object with same keys as other

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to declare a mapping of one object to another.

The first object can have any string keys and values of a generic type.

I want to map this object with the same keys, and the types of the values can be anything (but nice would be if I could extract them from the generic). Specifically these are properties of a class and the first is passed in the constructor.

```js
class C {
  ob1: {
    [key: string]: Wrapper<any>
  };
  ob2; // should have the same keys as ob1

  constructor(o?: { [key: string]: Wrapper<any> }) {
    this.ob1 = o;
    // map ob2 from o
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to do this is to make `C` itself a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) class with a type parameter `T` corresponding to either the type of `ob1` or `ob2`, and then use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to express "same keys but different/related values".  For example:

```
type MappedWrapper<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Wrapper<T[K]> }
class C<T> {
  ob1: MappedWrapper<T>
  ob2: T;
  constructor(o: MappedWrapper<T>) { // made param required here
    this.ob1 = o;
    this.ob2 = mapUnwrap(o); // some function that unwraps properties
  }
}
```

Here we say that `T` is the type of `ob2`, while `ob1` has the type `MappedWrapper<T>`, a mapped type where each property of `ob1` is mapped to a `Wrapper`-version.

---

Depending on the implementation and declaration of `Wrapper` and related types, such as:

```
type Wrapper<T> = { x: T };
function wrap<T>(x: T): Wrapper<T> {
  return { x };
}
function unwrap<T>(x: Wrapper<T>): T {
  return x.x;
}
function mapUnwrap<T>(x: MappedWrapper<T>): T {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).map(([k, v]) => [k, unwrap(v)])) as any as T;
}
```

you can verify that this works as expected:

```
const c = new C({ a: wrap(123), b: wrap("hello"), c: wrap(true) });
/* const c: C<{ a: number; b: string; c: boolean;}> */

c.ob1.a.x.toFixed(); // no error
c.ob2.b.toUpperCase(); // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#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)

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work with child-classes, then I say `class Sub<T> extends C<T>` in the constructor it tells me that the properties don't exist on `MappedWrapper<T>`

Comment: I need a [mcve] before I can even begin to know what's going on there.

Comment: Modified your example, just add ```class Sub<T> extends C<T> {
  constructor() {
    super({
      a: wrap(2)
    })
  }
}```

Comment: So perhaps you want `class Sub extends C<{ a: number }> {`...`}` instead?

Comment: Yes, but my wrapper takes more arguments, so it's not really possible for me to auto-wrap it

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you want me to say or do here.  If this is a follow-up question you might want to create a new post for it.  If it's part of the existing question then you might want to edit your post here to add the relevant information.  In either case it would be desirable to include a [mcve] so that anyone answering knows the full scope of the issue and what constitutes a solution.  Good luck!

Comment: Just wanted to mention this for completeness: I managed to get it to work even with child classes with inference types like here https://itnext.io/typescript-extract-unpack-a-type-from-a-generic-baca7af14e51